# Is there a function in Knockout.js to build an object from a data-bind attribute string?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0

I tried to run `JSON.parse($("input").attr("data-bind"))` but it throws an error.

Is there something similar in the Knockout library that I could somehow use?

I would like to construct an object of all the bindings relevant to an element, and combine it with bindings relevant to parent elements.

Would anyone happen to know what I can do to achieve this?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the error thrown?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 0.

Comment: Where the data-bind attribute value is "value: PORef, class: tsrVM.DisableWarehouseFields() ? 'force-disable' : 'mock-disabled'".

Even JSON.parse("{ " + dataBindVal + " }") gives the same result.

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work for you. You're adding expressions to the JSON (the ternary), as well as a variable, which is illegal in JSON. You're best bet... oh boy, is to go with the `Function` constructor, or parse the stuff yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout's binding strings are not valid JSON, so that's why you can't parse it as such.

The default parsing logic is exposed though. You can access it through a `bindingProvider` instance (have a look at [the source](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/bindingProvider.js) to see all available methods).

Here's a simple proof of concept you can start with:

```js
ko.applyBindings({});

const myDiv = document.querySelector("div")
console.log(
  ko.bindingProvider.instance.getBindings(myDiv, ko.contextFor(myDiv))
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="text: 'Hello', attr: { title: 'World' }"></div>
```